# What is the best way to update mysql tables using cron jobs?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, cron

I receive a CSV everyday at 5:19am. The info in the CSV is used to populate/update tables in my sql database.

I have 3 tables:

```
tempVehicle (temporary table, just for holding info), 

vehicle (contains most info, main table), 

and vehicleImages (table linked to vehicle by VIN).
```

I need to remove the info not contained in the new CSV from the tables and get the new info from the CSV into the tables.

I set it up as such:

1. Drop tempVehicle, to completely wipe the table
2. Re-Create tempVehicle, for a fresh table
3. Import CSV data into tempVehicle, to use as a temporary info holder
4. Delete all data from vehicleImages table, so I can remove items from the main table (vehicle)
5. Delete all data from vehicle table
6. Do an insert from tempVehicle to vehicle table
7. Update vehicleImages by exploding the image links from the CSV, then 'insert ignore' into vehicleImages

I have a total of 7 PHP files, each one associated with one of the steps above. I did this because they have to happen in a specific order and I couldn't figure out how to get the multi-query to work while keeping that specific order.

In a perfect scenario, I would love it to be set up using a single multi-query in one php file. I plan on using a cron job to run this file everyday and would rather not have to run several cron jobs.

So the questions I would like answered, if possible, are:

- Is there a better way to update the tables more efficiently?
- If not, is it possible to combine all my queries into one multi-query?

If anyone has any other suggestions, I'm open.

Comment: Answers: 1) YES. 2) Yes look at TRANSACTIONS

Comment: ___And for future reference:___
 To ask [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Create new tables, like `temp_{table}` populate it, then I think you can just rename it and not have to delete either table.  This should save some time, instead of deleting renaming deleting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do

- Create tempVehicle and tempVehicleImages , for a fresh table(s)
- Import CSV data into tempVehicle and tempVehicleImages, to use as a temporary info holder(s)
- Rename tempVehicle to vehicle, rename tempVehicleImages to vehicleImages

This should overwrite the existing table and at the same time remove the temp table (because it's renamed).

```
 RENAME TABLE tempVehicle TO vehicle

RENAME TABLE tempVehicleImages TO vehicleImages
```

You may have to also setup indexes after renaming, with Alter Table.

As a side note/pet peeve of mine:  Camel casing is not my preferred way to name tables, I would prefer vehicle and vehicle_image.  This way there is no casing pluralization issues.

But, this is just the way I do things (but it's your DB).

Normal table

- all lower case
- underlines for spaces
- non-plural

Junction (Bridge) tables  (Many to Many relationship)

- all lower case
- underlines for spaces
- plural

So if you had `vehicle` and `image`  you could have a Junction table `vehicles_images` for example.  That way I know when I see a plural table it's a junction table (two or more table names).  Otherwise I don't have to think if its vehicleImages, VehicleImages, vehiclesImages, vehiclesImage or any other combination.

Comment: I can't just rename tempVehicle to Vehicle due to the 'images' section in tempVehicle. The images are stored in tempVehicle as a comma separated list, which is why I explode them into the vehicleImages table

Comment: Create two temp tables and do the exploding/inserting before hand, then rename two tables.  Or in other words handle the images upfront, which is probably still cheaper.  There updated my answer (simple)

Comment: I wasn't able to just rename both tables. Kept getting the error 'this table already exists' so I had to drop the pre-existing table first. Managed to chop it down a few php files, but still have 4 different files.